# Using SQL to query a distinct pair based on a similar id

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am running into some trouble finding a way to query a pair, based on similar ids on a table.

I have a database schema that consists of something like this:

```
Class:
    *Course
    *Size
    *Class_ID

Partner:
    *Class_ID
    *Person_ID
    *Partner_ID

Person:
    *Name
    *Person_ID
    *Email
```

When partners are chosen in class, they are given the same partner ID. I am trying to write a query that queries all the partner pairs for 'Economics'. The query should be distinct pairs , ie. a,b and b,a shouldn't both be listed.

So far I have used a Join statement to query everything together.

```
Select * from Person Join Partner On Person.Person_ID = Partner.Partner_ID
Join Class On Class.Class_ID = Partner.Partner_ID WHERE Class.Course = 'Economics';
```

This query gives me a list of each individual person who has a partner in economics. I would like to be able to somehow turn this query into pairs.

I think the group_by Partner_ID function might be helpful, but I'm not sure how I would use it.

Comment: Sample input and output pls

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a way to get unique pairings from the Partner table where the course is "Economics", here's one way you could do it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN P1.Person_ID < P1.Partner_ID THEN P2.Name ELSE P3.Name END name1
     , CASE WHEN P1.Person_ID < P1.Partner_ID THEN P3.Name ELSE P2.Name END name2
     , C.Course
     , P1.Class_ID
FROM Partner P1
JOIN Person P2 ON P2.Person_ID = P1.Person_ID
JOIN Person P3 ON P3.Person_ID = P1.Partner_ID
JOIN Class C ON C.Class_ID = P1.Class_ID
WHERE C.Course = 'Economics'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN P1.Person_ID < P1.Partner_ID THEN P2.Name ELSE P3.Name END
       , CASE WHEN P1.Person_ID < P1.Partner_ID THEN P3.Name ELSE P2.Name END
       , C.Course
       , P1.Class_ID;
```